# Java username and password always returns true

Tags: java, arrays, passwords, char

I am working on a project and have been trying to impliment a username/password. Below you see the code. Whenever I click the login button, the username changes to bobsyouruncle, indicating to me that it has found a "true" value in the method. The issue is that it always does, regardless of input. This is made even more confusing because if I change the "return true" below to "return false" then I STILL get bobsyouruncle. Any suggestions?

```
    loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            Boolean authenticated = AuthenticateCredentials(usernameField.getText(),passwordField.getPassword());

            if(authenticated = true){
                usernameField.setText("Bobsyouruncle");
            } else {
                System.exit(0);
            }

        }
    });
```

Below is the method accessed.

```
private Boolean AuthenticateCredentials(String user, char[] pass) {
    //This is only a placeholder.
    String theCorrectAnswer = "42";
    String theCorrectUser = "FPrefect";
    char[] passcode = theCorrectAnswer.toCharArray();
    optionPanel.showInternalMessageDialog(securityPanel,"Eggs are not supposed to be green.");
    if (user.equals(theCorrectUser) && Arrays.equals(passcode,pass)) {
        return true;    
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

If anyone wants to tell me that I am already screwing up in creating a secure username and password to save me trouble down the road, that would be dandy, too.

Comment: Take a closer look at `if(authenticated = true){`. What does `=` do in Java?

Comment: if forgetting the double equals `==` is a common issue for you, you can try to write your conditions like `(immutable-value == mutable-value)` i.e. `(true == authenticated)` that way if you accidentally type `(true = authenticated)` you get a compile error instead of having to figure out why it's not working

Comment: @chancea True, but in case of boolean value simple `if (boolValue)` is simpler and safer then `if(boolValue==true)`. Also in case of `if (boolValue==false)` or `if(booValue!=true)` we can simply write it as `if (!boolValue)`.

Comment: And you should replace your `if(condition) return true; else return false;` with the simpler: `return (condition)`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the problem is that you're trying to compare two expressions with the `=` symbol, which means *assignment* in java. The *comparison* symbol is `==`.

However, if you change your code in this way:

```
if(authenticated == true)
```

you're still comparing an `Object` (`Boolean`) with a `primitive type` (`boolean`).

The correct way to do that is to use a `boolean`. Change the return value of your function form `Boolean` to `boolean`:

```
private boolean AuthenticateCredentials(String user, char[] pass) {
    return (user.equals("FPrefect") && Arrays.equals("42".toCharArray(), pass);
}
```

Then, do the same in your button listener:

```
boolean authenticated = AuthenticateCredentials(usernameField.getText(),passwordField.getPassword());
if(authenticated)
    usernameField.setText("Bobsyouruncle");
else
    System.exit(0);
```

Comment: And why OP should do all these changes?

Comment: It would be a much better answer if you explain the rationale.

Comment: @Pshemo - I've just edited my answer. Now it says the reason OP should do all these changes.

Comment: But why "*The correct way to do that is to use always a boolean*"? What is wrong with trying to compare `Boolean` with `boolean`? Unboxing will take care of it for us and change `Boolean` value into primitive `boolean` value for us.

Comment: To avoid, for example, this *garbage*: `public static Boolean f() { return null; }`

Comment: That is actually one of advantages of `Boolean` over `boolean`. `null` represents *unset* state which may be very useful, so I wouldn't call it a *garbage*.

Comment: Yes, if we talk generally it's true, but in *this* particular case, what's the advantage of use `Boolean` instead of `boolean`? None but get confused.

Comment: OK, I agree that in this case `Boolean` is not needed and `boolean` would be enough. But this is not solution of OP main problem, but minor improvement, which means your answer wasn't really an answer, but it was more like comment with code example. Normally I would down-vote it and move on, but since you are new on SO and most mew members tend to treat down-votes more personally I preferred to ask you question which would hopefully improve your answer and give OP more info about it. And that plan worked since now it contains info about `=` vs `==`, plus OP can learn more from our comments.

Answer (score 10):

You are assigning with `=`, but the comparison operator needed here is `==`.  But, `authenticated` is already a `boolean`, so just use:

```
if(authenticated){
```